# Custom eventemitter in ionic range component is not working on production

Tags: ionic3

I wrote 2 eventemitter inside the ionic range component code like "ionStart" and "ionStop". 
These events works fine on running on device but not on production release.
I figured out that on production release or if i run on device with --prod flag, the observers of my custom eventemitters are empty as you can see in the link of  image below. 
I spend lots of time to solve this issue with no success.
Please help me!

[observer in custom eventemitter is empty in production release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkYs2.png)